# Help with java File

Tags: java

```
File[] roots = File.listRoots();  
for(File root: roots)  
{  
    System.out.println(root);  
}
```

I am new to java,i want to know how can i copy the result of this code in a String instead of print them. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
File[] roots = File.listRoots();   
for(File root: roots)  
{  
      string.append(root).append("\n");  
}
System.out.println(string);
```

Comment: @mauricio I don't know why it shows I removed the multiple appends, I was only trying to change two typos :)

Comment: a nasty race condition in SO maybe :P

Comment: @mauricio personally, I always use the double append also... the whole point of StringBuilder is to remove those concatenations :)P

Answer (score 4):

Look at [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
final File[] roots = File.listRoots();  
for(final File root: roots)  
{  
    if (sb.length() > 0)   sb.append("\n");
    sb.append(root);  
}
System.out.println(sb.toString()); // toString() not strictly necessary to println
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  File[] roots = File.listRoots();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  for(File root: roots)  
  {  
    sb.append(root.getName());  
  }

  String s = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = Arrays.toString(roots);
```